# Streamline and reduce unwanted output being displayed

Tags: python, ping

This is my code to to check the status which is associated with the host, I just wanna print the status(up/down) and avoid the entire pinging process being displayed on the terminal.

```
import os
hostname = "google.com"
response = os.system("ping -c 1" + hostname)

if response == 0:
    print hostname, 'up'
else:
    print hostname, 'down'
```

Comment: There are a couple of products available like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ping/ that use ICMP. I haven't tried any of them. They require that you have root status on 'nix or be an administrator on Windows.

Comment: I think using a python ping library (mentioned by Bill Bell) is the best option. If you insist using os.system, try redirect you output (ex.  > /dev/null) to hide it: `response = os.system("ping -c 1 {} >/dev/null 2>/dev/null".format(hostname))`

Comment: bingo...worked...thanks man...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess 
import re
hostname = "google.com"  

with subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c 1", "-t 3", hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
  match = re.findall(r'1 packets received', proc.stdout.read().decode())
  if match:
    print(hostname + ' is up')
  else:
    print(hostname + ' is down')
```

result:

```
google.com is up
```

For python 2.7:

```
test = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c 1", "-t 3", hostname],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
match = re.findall(r'1 packets received', test.communicate()[0])
if match:
  print(hostname + ' is up')
else: 
  print(hostname + ' is down')
```

Comment: getting this error    "with subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c 1", "-t 3", hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
AttributeError: __exit__"

Comment: @user7576454 Without a full traceback...all I can is that this is working code. Older versions of python do have some issue with subprocess, check which version of python you're on.

Comment: the version is 2.7.12

Comment: @user7576454, yep python2 handles subprocess differently, I added variant solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I made one like this.
I will customize this later some time to send email.

I keep you posted.
Regards,

import os
   hostname = "google.com"

if os.name == 'nt' or os.name == 'NT':
       response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
   else:
       response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

if response == 0:
       print(hostname, 'up')
   else:
       print(hostname, 'down')
       ''' to do add option to send email if ping fail''